# Display Multiple clients Name at Server side using Socket Connection in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In *Windows-Form Application C#*, I have done multiple client connection to a single server using socket connection and I can send numbers from multiple clients to single server. But the problem is that, at the server I am not able to differentiate which client is sending which number, so I need to display `Client_1`, `Client_2`, `Client_3` and so on differently at the server side application. Please let me know how it would be better?

SERVER( at the OnDataReceived() Method how it can be changed?)

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Socket_Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        const int MAX_CLIENTS = 30;

        public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
        private Socket m_mainSocket;
        private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[30];
        private int m_clientCount = 0;


        public StreamWriter STW;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PortNumber = "1755";
            try
            {

                string portStr = PortNumber;
                int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
                m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                           SocketType.Stream,
                                           ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
                m_mainSocket.Listen(4);

                m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);

                this.BackgroundWorker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Startinfiniteloop));

                this.BackgroundWorker.Start();



            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }

        public void Startinfiniteloop()
        {

            for (int initial_value = 0; ; initial_value++)
            {


                try
                {


                    Dictionary<string, int> d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                    d2["c2"] = initial_value;




                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Storing_Number.Items.Clear()));
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Storing_Number.Items.Add(d2["c2"])));

                    //Delay  Thread             
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    NumberSend(  d2["c2"] + "\n");
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Sending_Box.Items.Add("Sending_To_CLIENT:     " + d2["c2"] + "\n")));
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Sending_Box.TopIndex = Sending_Box.Items.Count - 1));

                   //  this.BackgroundWorker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(NumberSend));

              //  this.BackgroundWorker.Start();


                           // STW = new StreamWriter(Sending_Box.Items[initial_value].ToString());
                          //  STW.WriteLine(Sending_Box.Items[initial_value]);
                           // STW.AutoFlush = true;

                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {

                }
            }


        }


        public void NumberSend(string mesg)
        {

            try
            {


                Object objData = mesg;

                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < m_clientCount; i++)
                {

                    if (m_workerSocket[i] != null)
                    {
                        if (m_workerSocket[i].Connected)
                        {
                            m_workerSocket[i].Send(byData);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }


        public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                m_workerSocket[m_clientCount] = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);


                WaitForData(m_workerSocket[m_clientCount]);
                ++m_clientCount;




                String str = String.Format("Client # {0} connected", m_clientCount);

                Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxMsg.Clear()));
                Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxMsg.AppendText(str)));
                m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }

        public class SocketPacket
        {
            public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
            public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
        }


        public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                {
                    pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;// could be this one!!!
                soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,
                                   theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                   SocketFlags.None,
                                   pfnWorkerCallBack,
                                   theSocPkt);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }

        public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
                int iRx = 0;
                iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
                                         0, iRx, chars, 0);
                System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBoxSendMsg.AppendText(szData)));
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBoxSendMsg.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)));
                WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseSockets();

            Close();
        }

        String GetIP()
        {
            String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

            String IPStr = "";

            foreach (IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
            {
                if (ipaddress.IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
                {
                    IPStr = IPStr + ipaddress.ToString();
                    return IPStr;
                }

            }
            return IPStr;
        }


        void CloseSockets()
        {
            if (m_mainSocket != null)
            {
                m_mainSocket.Close();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m_clientCount; i++)
            {
                if (m_workerSocket[i] != null)
                {
                    m_workerSocket[i].Close();
                    m_workerSocket[i] = null;
                }
            }
        }





        public Thread BackgroundWorker { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @SpaceSteak : Check out my program, thank you

Comment: Can anyone please help me how to Add **_client ID_** for each client connected in this **_server program_** above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `OnClientConnect()`, the IAsyncResult object should have information on the client. Where you do `++m_clientCount;` you could setup a dictionary with the unique info from each client and their ID (IP, port). Then in `OnDataReceived()` you could just `GetClientID(Socket client)`.

More info can be found on:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that in the future, please post a **simplest version** of your issue, so that others don't have to go through the entire code.